# What AWS disk options should I use for my EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Created a new Ubuntu c3.xlarge instance and when I get to storage options I get the option to change ROOT to General Purpose SSD, Provisioned IOPS or magnetic, also if I pick Provisioned IOPS i can set another value. Additional data storage under Instance Store 0 has no options but if change to EBS then I have the same options.

I'm really struggling to understand:

1. The speed of each option
2. the costs of each option

The Amazon documentation is very unclear

I'm using this instance to transfer data from text files into a Postgres relational database, these files have to be processed  line by line with a number of INSERT statements per line so is slow on my local computer (5 million rows of data takes 15 hours). Originally the database was separately on RDS but it was incredibly slow, so I installed the  database locally on the instance itself remove network latency  which has speed up things a bit but it is still considerably slower than my local humble linux server.

Looking at the instance logs whilst loading the data CPU instance is only at 6% so now thinking that disk may be limiting the factor. The database will be using the / (Not sure if SSD or magnetic - how can I find out) disk and the data files are on the /mnt (using Instance Store 0) disk.

I only need this instance to do two things:

1. Load database from datafiles
2. Create Lucene Search Index from database

(so the database is just an interim step)

The Search Index is transferred to an EBean Server and then I don;t need this instance for another month when I then repeat the process with new data so with that in mind I can afford to spend more money for faster processing because I'm only going to use 1 day a month, then I can stop the instance and incur no further costs ?

Please what can I do to determine the problem and speed things up ?

Comment: A provisioned IOPS is the best bet you can have, its configurable but may cost a little more, then the SSD, general case SSD is good, yours is IO intensive work so go for SSD or if you have ample money then provisioned IOPS

Comment: @Brij Raj Singh , thx what does the default Store 0 use ?

Comment: default storage is Magnetic drive, and its damn slow, I have used the SSD with my Mysql based db and File driven ops and its crazy quick, You should have selected the primary drive as SSD itself when creating the instance, but you can add more volumes and keep them ssd

Comment: @Brij Raj Singh thx so is there any difference between leaving the extra disk as Instance0 whihc seems to use SSD and changing it to an EBS SSD ?

Comment: sorry didn't got the q. , can you do a df -h and show me the state of your disks, the /dev/sda1 is magnetic or ssd

Comment: I was referring to the second disk you get on non-micro instances.I cant see anything in df -h to show disk type

Comment: df -T , so you have a basic disk which is magnetic, and an extra disk in the machine which is SSD, and you are wondering if you can change it to ssd or change your primary disk at /dev/sda1 to the ebs ssd (I am not sure if one can change the disk type)

Comment: No need to change types Im in experimental mode so I can create new instance, no my question was that extra disk is just called instance0 but you can change to ECB I think in both cases they are SSD so what is the difference, but what would type show to indicate magnetic, SSD ecetera.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my personal guideline:

- If the volume is small (<33G) and only require a eventual burst in performance, such as a boot volume, use magnetic drives.
- If you need predictable performance and high throughput, use PIOPS volumes and EBS optimized instances.
- Otherwise, use General Purpose SSD.

Comment: why is magnetic drive prefereable to SSD if small ?

Comment: and is there any difference between the default genral purpose SSD and EBS (but not IOPS) SSD ?

Comment: Per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSOptimized.html , the expected performance (within 10% of baseline performance 99.9% of the time) applies to General purpose SSDs, not just PIOPS.  General purpose SSD is much cheaper than PIOPS for the same performance, but it tops out at 3000IOPS rather than 4000IOPS.  A 1TB drive general purpose SSD has 3000 IOPS as the baseline, not only as burst.  If you need more than 3000IOPS, you probably should be investigating raiding your SSDs together.  PIOPS is rarely a good choice.

Comment: @paul-taylor, that would be because at GP SSD is 3 IOPS per GB and Magnetic is 100 IOPS with bursts at half the cost. For example, a 20 GB volume would have 60 IOPS and cost 0.20/mo, a magnetic would deliver 100 IOPS baseline for $0.10/mo (us-east, only storage cost, no io considered). And yes, GP SSD and IOPS SSD are different, as Brian explained.

Comment: @Julio Faerman so Im assuming higher IOPS = Faster, I dont understand why SSD only faster for larger SSD's (i can see 3OPS per GB but why), is this peculiar just to AWS or applies to SSDs in geneneral ?

Comment: @paul-taylor Just to AWS. EBS volumes are not one physical drive, but a storage service backed by SSD and Magnetic drive types. The service will throttle GP SSD volumes to 3 IOPS/GB with bursts to 3K IOPS, regardless of the underlying SSD throughput. Physical SSDs will have very different throughput, durability, availability and cost characteristics.

Comment: @PaulTaylor No problem, my pleasure, but why what? What could i make clearer?

Comment: @JulioFaerman if IOPS ( I/O per second) is an indication of speed why is the speed proportional to the size of the disk or does it not work like that ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor This is just the way AWS decided to structure the EBS volume types. For Provisioned IOPS volumes you can decide (and pay) separately for volume size and IO rate. for GP SSD volumes they will be 3 IOPS per GB, with burts to 3k IOPS. This blog post would dive deeper on that: http://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/aws/new-ssd-backed-elastic-block-storage/

Comment: ok, I dont really understand, but I understand it better than I did so marked your answer as correct.

Answer (score 4):

Your CPU is only at 6%, maybe you can try to use multi-process?

Did you test your remote instance's volume's I/O performance?

PIOPS is expensive, but it did not significantly better than gp2, the only advantage is `stable`.

For example, I create a 500G gp2 and a 500G PIOPS with 1500IOPS, then I try to insert and find 1,000,000 documents by mongodb, then I check the io performanace by such as mongoperf/iostat/mongostat/dstat

Each volume's iops performance is expect to 1500,
but gp2's iops is unstable, almost from 700 to 1600(r+w), if only read, it can brust to 4000, if only write, it just reach 800.
piops is perfect stable, it iops is almost 1470.

To your situation, I suggest to consider about gp2 (volume size depend on your iops demand, 500G gp2 = 1500iops, 1T gp2 = 3000iops(maximum))